# Visual Studio Team Services (TFS Online) - Restrict access to code

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I need to restrict access to source code for certain users (e.g. testers from a third-party company), but still give them access to the project for logging bugs etc.  How can I achieve this?  I cannot see a permission in the security tab that relates to source code access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this in GIT TFS by removing the users from the "Contributor" Group.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming TFVC: Right click on the folder you want to exclude from the "Code" tab in the web and go to "Security". If you're using Git, choose "Manage Repository".

The Security area in the admin console does not show security for all aspects of the application.